# Long string field for Atlas in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, string

In QGIS 3.4 I need a long string field to store one description (2000 characters) for each point. The project is based on *.shp files however they manage only 254. 
I need to compile lots of formats in an atlas.
Any tips or suggestions for different file format?

Comment: http://switchfromshapefile.org/

Comment: Since the answer is "Use anything but shapefile", and no other requirements are offered, this is the very definition of an *opinion-based* question.